# Are fractional Sobolev spaces in dimension one embedded in $L^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fractional-calculus, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider the space

\begin{equation*}
X(\Omega) := \left\lbrace u \in L^{2}(\Omega) \iint_{\Omega\times \Omega}\frac{(u(x)-u(y))^{2}}{|x-y|^{2}}dxdy ;  u= 0 \textrm{ a.e in } \mathbb{R} \setminus \Omega\right\rbrace,
\end{equation*}
where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$.
We see that $X(\Omega)$ is a Hilbert space with inner product
\begin{equation*}
\left\langle u, v \right\rangle_{X(\Omega)} := \displaystyle\iint_{\Omega\times \Omega}\dfrac{(u(x)-u(y))(v(x)-v(y))}{|x-y|^{2}}dxdy.
\end{equation*}

It is well known that if $|\Omega| < \infty$ then $||u||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq C||u||_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)}$ (see Theorem 8.8 in Brezis's Functional Analysis).

**Question**. Is there an analogous estimate valid for $X(\Omega)$?

Comment: May be "Proposition 2.1" from the "Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces" (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449711001254) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AlecKalinin No. In this case we obtain $W^{1,2}(\Omega) \subset X(\Omega)$. I would like to show that $ X(\Omega) \subset L^{\infty}(\Omega) $. This inclusion is true for traditional Sobolev spaces, but I don't know if it is true for the fractional ones.